# heroku throws error without telling me which file the error is in: Invalid numeric literal at line 31, column 7

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to push a commit to heroku but it's failing giving this error

```
Total 93 (delta 62), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Node.js app detected
```

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 31, column 7
```

```
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app

To git@heroku.com:~.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:~.git'
```

Which file is it referring the error at line 31 is in?

The app is working fine locally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case it was package.json. It doesn't like comments in there, either...

I emptied out all the deps and dev-deps and pushed and it worked. Try that. (Obvs you'll have to put them back in).

Also be careful with the syntax for module versions like '*' and '^' - that was the first set of errors I got that generated the problem...

UPDATE: Ignore the last paragraph: the semver markers above are fine IF your version of node is >0.10 ...

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem as well.  It turned out to be the editor I was using was encoding my quotes incorrectly.  Changed to Sublime Text and issue resolved.